# PNG TrayIcon transparency on Windows

Tags: java, png, transparency, trayicon

I'm trying to use a transparent PNG as the icon for my Java application. The image on the JFrame and task bar work great. However, when I use the image with a TrayIcon, I get a black matte background around the edge of the PNG.

Has anybody else come across this issue? I would really like to use a PNG instead of GIF or JPEG.

Answer (score 1):

With [Java6](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javase6/systemtray/), a PNG picture should be used for `TrayIcon`, but as mentioned in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331407), check:

- the background color chosen to represent the transparent pixels
- the [transparency options](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics)
- the resolution of the icon
- alternate format like SVG (provided you are using external library like [Batik](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/), and [conversion mechnism to `java.awt.Image`](http://markmail.org/message/pfcceqjgy2mxvy6m))

Comment: The `TrayIcon` constructor takes an image. Are you sure that Java can create an image from an SVG file?

Comment: @mklhmnn You are right, but with a Java library like Batik , you can create an Image from a SVG file. See also thread http://markmail.org/message/pfcceqjgy2mxvy6m

Comment: @mklhmnn: not tested. And the OP didn't return to give us any feedback. Do you have any new element to add to this issue?