# Best image format for tray icon

Tags: java, image, icons, format, tray

I created a Java application with tray icon. I am using a transparent `png` image. However, the rendered icon is very ugly on all platforms, including Windows 7 and Linux.

Are there any good practices for creating tray icons (e.g. format, size, etc.)?

Comment: I'm not sure what the best image file format is but the size is 16x16px in the systray.

Comment: is it solved currently ?

Answer (score 2):

In windows, you should use the `.ico` format. It may contain multiple icons with different sizes.
In Linux I guess `png` is the standard. Just don't try to scale it. Pre-create multiple versions of the same image with different sizes.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "known solution" for this problem as far as i know. You should switch your transparent icons to square ones. You can check this question for deeper information;

[java TrayIcon using image with transparent background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331407/java-trayicon-using-image-with-transparent-background)