# How to display desktop notifications?

Tags: java, linux, notifications, telegram, trayicon

Actually I'm using trayIcon with the displayMessage method but I'm having a problem which looking on the internet and [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331407/java-trayicon-using-image-with-transparent-background) seems to be unsolvable: the trasparent background in the image gets gray on Linux.

So, can you tell me if there are any alternatives? or something similar to Telegram Desktop notifications?

Thanks in advance.